# Is it possible to hide Homepage Ribbon Button in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

There's a possibility to hide Form's Ribbon button in crm by java script.
But i cant hide Home page Ribbon button.
Is there any ways to hide home page ribbon button using java script?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Because some comments are lost in a removed answer, I rewrite here.

Ribbon customization (also the one inside the homepage) must be done editing the `XML` definition, not by `DOM` manipulation of the element.

More information here:

[Define Ribbon Display Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328560.aspx)

and here:

[Define Ribbon Enable Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334682.aspx)

Is also suggested to use a ribbon editor, like this one:

[Ribbon Workbench for Dynamics CRM 2011](http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Ribbon Editor is also a very good tool.

You can download it from here: 
[Visual Ribbon Editor](http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com)

To edit the ribbon manually, have look at [this](http://garethtuckercrm.com/2011/02/23/hiding-a-ribbon-button-in-crm-2011)  article.